# SQL Combine two tables in select statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, union

I have a situation where I want to combine two tables for queries in a select statement, and I haven't found a working solution yet.

The Situation:
Table A
Table B

Both A and B have identical fields but distinct populations. I have other queries that are pulling from each table separately.

I want to build a query that pulls from them as if they were one table. There are no instances of records being in both tables.

My research so far led me to think the FULL OUTER JOIN was what I wanted, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that when I'm not really joining them *on* any field and it failed in my tests. So I searched for append options thinking that might more accurately represent what I'm trying to do and the INSERT INTO looked promising but less so for select statements. Is there a way to do this or do I need to create a third table that's the combination of the first two to query from?

.

This is being done as an Excel VBA query to Access via DAO. I'm building up SQL statements piece by piece in my VBA code based on user-selected options and then pulling the results into Excel for use. AS such my hope is to be able to only alter the FROM statement (since I'm building up the queries piecemeal) to effect this so that any other aspects of the select statement won't be impacted. Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [combining two select statements to return one result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790938/combining-two-select-statements-to-return-one-result)

Comment: As stated UNION is what you want. The [documentation](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010341541.aspx) describes how to use it with some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `UNION` the tables to do this:

```
SELECT StuffYouWant
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM TableA
      UNION  ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM TableB) c
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! I didn't realize I could also execute further select statements in the FROM clause of my parent statement; I dropped this in my code and everything else works perfectly from there!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a
UNION
SELECT * FROM b
```

Make sure the `a` table and the `b` table have the same number of columns and the corresponding columns have the same data type